# Failed to download plugins repository - Error displays when trying to install plugin from Plugin Manager

Tags: c#-4.0, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Open the JMeter -> Selects the plugin Manager from Options.-> It will displays the error message as attached file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings.
As [Using Behind the Proxy](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/#Using-Behind-the-Proxy) documentation says:

> Plugins Manager respects JMeter's proxy settings. However, to avoid editing the properties files, we recommend to launch JMeter with additional parameters to pass it the proxy settings:

`JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried these, but because of some minor mistake not able to do it. Now, it's working as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @KrupaBrahmbhatt , great! If your question is solved, it would be good for community if you accept the answer as correct. Thanks!